# Цикл for не работает с массивом

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<h1>Привет мир!</h1>
<p>Моя не первая веб-страничка.</p>

<script>
var stol = ["компьютер", "мышка", "лампа", "переходник"];
for (var i = 0; i < stol.lenght; i++) {
    console.log("На моем столе лежит " + stol[i] + ".");
}
</script>
```

//по идее этот код должен выводить все строки находящиеся в массиве с препиской "На моем столе лежит ", но код просто не делает ничего, почему?

Comment: Опечатка в слове `lenght`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У Вас опечатка должно быть не `stol.lenght` а `stol.length`

```js
var stol = ["компьютер", "мышка", "лампа", "переходник"];
for (var i = 0; i < stol.length; i++) {
  console.log("На моем столе лежит " + stol[i] + ".");
}
```

```html
<h1>Привет мир!</h1>
<p>Моя не первая веб-страничка.</p>
```

так же, для обхода массива можно использовать `forEach`

```js
var stol = ["компьютер", "мышка", "лампа", "переходник"];
stol.forEach(el =>  console.log(`На моем столе лежит ${el}.`))
```

```html
<h1>Привет мир!</h1>
<p>Моя не первая веб-страничка.</p>
```